# Property dependency and JPA

Tags: jpa, properties, dependencies

I have to model a situation, where I have an entity which can be one of four values and two of these four states can have an additional comment.

My first idea was to define a class, which has two member fields, one as Enum, one as String. The Enum has four elements. But I have to model a constraint too, that only on value 2 and 3 the comment can be set.

How would you model that? Four different entities and inheritance on JPA? Or like the Enum example above?

Thanks a lot
Andre

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution is alright. Just implement the setter like this:

```
public void setComment(String comment) {
    if (state != State.STATE1 && state != State.STATE2) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("A comment can't be set when the state is " + state);
    }
}
```

Using inheritance is not a good idea: When an entity has a given type, it can't become something other. So changing the state would be impossible with an inheritance strategy.